# Jump starting a car without battery terminals connected

Tags: battery, starting, car

Back around 1978, my wife and I bought an old Fiat 124 sedan. It was at the owner's house and the battery was dead. I disconnected the battery terminals and connected the jumper cables from our car directly to the battery terminals and the car started.
After the Fiat was started, I connected the cables back to the dead battery, and I could tell the Fiat's system suddenly had a heavy load on it but continued to run.
It was starting to get dark and I got the Fiat home as quickly as possible without turning on lights, radio, etc.
Made it home fine and got a new battery the next day.

My questions are: 
can modern cars be started this way?
Will it damage the electrical/electronic system?

Thanks!
Chaz

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

I *can* be started that way, but I wouldn't advise it.  The issue is leaving the car running while reconnecting the battery cables.  You run the risk of damaging the alternator if one of the "jumper" clamps slips off.